# How to activate Android localization Files editor

Tags: android, eclipse, localization, text-editor

I can not find Android localization Files editor. I tried to reinstall Eclipse, have tried to use other versions of Eclipse and Java JDK, but it is inefficient.
I can not find 'Sequoyah Android Localization Editor' and 'Sequoyah Localization Tools' plugins. In all versions of Eclipse, it is absent.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the desire to help!

Comment: Android tools are not part of the standard Eclipse distributions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Barely two days of searching, I found the answer myself!

Use the following eclipse update site: http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.1/

**Make sure you uncheck 'Group items by category' or you will not see any available packages!**

Select the 'Sequoyah android Localization Editor' and install the package.

Right click on one of your 'strings.xml' file and select open with -> other -> 'Localization Files Editor'

Comment: In case others hate to read, UNCHECK `Group items by category` - missing this tip wasted so much time. Cheers +1